# Interface List method add(int index, E element); Why i have UnsupportedOperationEception?

Tags: java, list, testing, collections

I'm make unit test Interface List. Simple code but i can't understand, why `testAdd()` throws UnsupportedOperationException but `testSet()` do not throws this exception.

```
public class testList {
    private static List<Integer> testList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
        testGet();
        testSet();
        testAdd();
    }

    private static void init() {
        testList = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4);
    }

    private static void testGet() {
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2), testList.get(2));
    }

    private static void testSet() {
        testList.set(6, 5);
        assertEquals(new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4}, testList.toArray());
    }

    private static void testAdd() {
        testList.add(0, 1);
        assertEquals(new Integer[]{1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4}, testList.toArray());
    }
}
```

This is from AbstractList

[image]

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `testAdd` should fail anyways

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, sorry, it's just part of the total test :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList
```

Returns an wrapper to the original list, so you will not be able to change the list length (`add()` or `remove()`).

Comment: You're completely right. I'll update my answer

Comment: Also, please make a minimal effort to find duplicates before you attempt to answer questions. This one in particular has been asked and answered hundreds of times. Instead, flag (or vote once you have enough reputation) to close as such.

Answer (score -2):

`Arrays.toList(T... t)`retrun a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` not `java.util.ArrayList`

this class is a add methods is extends of `AbstractList`
like this code

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

so throws a UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: It is best to provide some text outside of the code block to explain what you are trying to show

Comment: sorry,I'm a sprog